# Can someone help me with this? Logic using natural deduction

Tags: logic, proof

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I think I am missing how to pass line 12 of the subproof to the general proof. Can someone show me whats wrong? Thank you. [image]

Comment: Can you give the sources of the abbreviations used in the demonstration?

Comment: Quite right... but lines 7 and 11 are not necessary: the conclusion follows from 3 and the two sub-proofs by Disjunction Elimination.